# Saving multiple plots to one pdf file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to save multiple plots in one pdf file.

can anyone help with the following code?

what is wrong with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import random as rand


pdfFile = PdfPages("output.pdf")

for i in range(10):
    xVals = [x for x in range(20)]
    yVals = [rand.randint(50,100) for x in xVals]
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    fig = plt.plot(xVals , yVals)
    plt.xlabel('Data point') 
    plt.ylabel('Strain [us]') 
    plt.title(i)

    #plt.show()

    pdfFile.savefig(fig)
    print(i)

pdfFile.close()
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted

Comment: @MadPhysicist it gives me an error and did not work (TypeError: Unhashable type: 'list')

Answer (score 0):

[`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) returns as list of `Line2D`s (in your case just one). From this line you need to get the figure using [`get_figure`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.get_figure.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.get_figure):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import random as rand


pdfFile = PdfPages("output.pdf")

for i in range(10):
    xVals = [x for x in range(20)]
    yVals = [rand.randint(50,100) for x in xVals]
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    line, = plt.plot(xVals , yVals)
    plt.xlabel('Data point') 
    plt.ylabel('Strain [us]') 
    plt.title(i)

    #plt.show()

    pdfFile.savefig(line.get_figure())
    print(i)

pdfFile.close()
```

When no figure is specified in [`savefig`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_pdf_api.html?highlight=pdfpages#matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages) the current figure is saved, so you could also simply write:

```
plt.plot(xVals , yVals)
pdfFile.savefig()
```